# How do you make a 2-d array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I want to make a 2D array dij(i and j are subscripts). I want to be able to do dij = di,j-1+(di,j-1 - di-1,dj-1)/(4^j-1) My idea for this it to make to 1D arrays and then combine them into a 2D array. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  What is the starting data for constructing the array?

Comment: the array dij is a 2D array 0:nx0:n for example
dij = [0:n;0:n]

Comment: How big is n by the way?

Comment: I think Leo meant: What are the starting values for the 0th row and column? Your formula for `dij` is a function of values in the previous row and column, so you have to initialize the 0th ones to some value to start things off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since n is 10, I would definitely just preallocate the array like this:

```
d = zeros(n,n)
```

Then put in your d(1,1) element and handle your first row explicitly (I'm guessing that you just don't include the terms that deal with the previous row) before looping through the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that matlab starts numbering from 1.  Then, useful functions are

```
zeros(m,n) % Makes a 2D array with m rows and n columns, filled with zero
ones(m,n)  % Same thing with one
reshape(a , m , n)   % Turns an array with m*n elements into a m,n square
```

The last one is useful if you construct a linear array but then want to make a square one out of it.  (If you want to count up columns instead of rows, `reshape(a,n,m)'`.

You can also perform an outer product of two vectors:

```
> [1;2;3]*[1 2 3]
ans =

   1   2   3
   2   4   6
   3   6   9
```

To actually build an array with the math you're describing, you'll probably have to loop over it in at least one axis with a for loop.